# Is there a way to use multiprocessing with Python's Sphinx to make it faster?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

We're using Sphinx to generate several hundreds of HTML reports for our analysis reports daily. We're continuously making our process faster and Sphinx is quickly becoming the long pole. So...

1. Is there a way to speed up the HTML generation by using multiprocessing?
2. If not, can we generate any sub directories concurrently?

Has anyone looked into this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could sphinx-multiprocessing be the answer?

https://bitbucket.org/DasIch/sphinx-multiprocessing

Comment: You could also consider using a machine with an SSD. That is one very good way of improving performance.  Storm on Demand offers SSD-based cloud servers.  Maybe that could be a way to solve your problem?